# lua oop how to call superclass constructor

Tags: oop, lua

I need helps on writing OOP on LUA. I am following [this tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectOrientationTutorial). However, I have no idea on how to call superclass constructor.

```
-- Base class
setmetatable(BaseClass, {
  __call = function (cls, ...)
    local self = setmetatable({}, cls)
    self._value = '12345'
    return self
  end,
})

-- Derived Class
setmetatable(DerivedClass, {
  __index = BaseClass, -- this is what makes the inheritance work
  __call = function (cls, ...)
    local self = ???
    -- How to call superclass constructor here?
    return self
  end,
})
function DerivedClass:haha()
  print(self._value)
  self._value = 0 -- Works on _value for example
  print(self._value)
end

-- Create instance
instance = DerivedClass()
assert_not_nil(instance._value) -- instance._value always nil here...
instance:haha() -- print 12345 and print 0
```

I have tried following
`local self = setmetatable({}, BaseClass)` or `local self = setmetatable({}, BaseClass())`

None of them works.

Furthermore, what is the arguments `cls` refer to on __call if I execute code `DerivedClass()` ?

Thanks

Comment: Try `local self = setmetatable(BaseClass(), {__index=cls})`

Comment: It would be helpful to see some code that shows how you want to use this, it could affect the answer.

Comment: @Schollii I have included an example showing how I would like to use those objects. Actually, Egor Skriptunoff codes work perfectly.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Can you post your answer below so that I can vote up and end this question? Moreover, would you elaborate more about the 2nd arguments? Why we need an __index and what is cls refers to? Thanks

Comment: @MondWan - Sorry, I'm too lazy to write complete answers.  `cls` (the first argument for a function pointed by `__call`) is the object being called (`DerivedClass` in your case). `{__index=cls}` is a usual metatable, of course.